# Ajax retorno de informação do PHP

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Amigos tenho um procedimento em php onde existe um laço "for", toda vez que ele retorna para o inicio ele dispara uma informação que é recebida na função Jquery/Ajax que a aciona. 
A questão é que os dados somente são exibidos para o usuário ao final do loop e eu precisava que os dados fossem disponibilizados toda vez que o php retornasse a informação, segue um exemplo do que eu preciso.

```
//função em ajax
function teste(){
$.ajax({
   type:'POST',
   url:'fiscal/teste',
   data:{
        ids:obj //obj é um array de ids de uma seleção em um grid
        },
   success: function (data) {
     $("#debug").text(data);
         },
   })
}

//Função em PHP
public function teste(Request $req){
    $i=0;
    while ($i<=10){
        print_r($req->ids[$i]);
        $i++;
        sleep(1);
    }
}
```

esse código só disponibiliza para os dados para o cliente quando o while termina.

Comment: E você precisa que o resultado do `print_r` seja enviado para o cliente mesmo sem ter terminado o laço?

Comment: Seria isso https://pastebin.com/jywWA1T7 ?

Comment: Anderson, na verdade o print_r (que so eh print_r para exemplificar mas poderia ser um return ou echo) é enviado a cada passagem no loop, o problema é qie p Ajax so repassa para a view quaindo o loop acaba, retornando todos os dados de uma so vez na tela, mas na verdade essa rotina vai fazer a transmissao de notas fiscais e como o webservice da nota carioca so aceita 150 rps por vez e o cliente transmite pelo menos 900 eu preciso que ele divida em blocos de 150 e a cada envio ele informasse que enviou o bloco 1 2 3 etc, mas ele ate faz so que ele so exibe na view quando ja foi tudo enviado

Comment: Valdeir, acredito que minha questao nao esta no php e sim no ajax, mesmo assim obrigado.